# Add columns in pandas dataframe dynamically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following code to load dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

ufo = pd.read_csv('csv_path')
print(ufo.loc[[0,1,2] , :])
```

which gives following output, see the structure of the csv

```
          City Colors Reported Shape Reported State             Time
0       Ithaca             NaN       TRIANGLE    NY   6/1/1930 22:00
1  Willingboro             NaN          OTHER    NJ  6/30/1930 20:00
2      Holyoke             NaN           OVAL    CO  2/15/1931 14:00
```

Now, I want to add an extra column based on existing column.
I have a list which consist of indices of participating columns.
It can be **0,1** or **0,2,3** or **1,2,3** anything.

I need to create it dynamically.
I could come up with following

```
df1['combined'] = df1['City']+','+df1['State']
```

Putting index doesn't seem to work.
I want to join those columns. using `','.join()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the data types of all the columns you want to `join` are `str`, you can use `[]` with integer to pick up the columns and use `apply` to join them:

```
df[[0,2,3]].apply(','.join, axis=1)

#0      Ithaca,TRIANGLE,NY
#1    Willingboro,OTHER,NJ
#2         Holyoke,OVAL,CO
#dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

If the list of indices is `l`, you can use [`pd.Series.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
df[df.columns[l[0]]].astype(str).str.cat([df[df.columns[i]].astype(str) for i in l[1: ]], sep=',')
```

---

**Example**

```
In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [2, 'b'], 'c': [3, 'd']})

In [19]: df[df.columns[l[0]]].astype(str).str.cat([df[df.columns[i]].astype(str) for i in l[1: ]], sep=',')
Out[19]: 
0    1,2
1    2,b
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Comment: I believe this is the same: `df[[l[0]]].str.cat(df[l[1:]], sep=',')`

Comment: @mdurant Thanks. I suspect you might be right in principle, but your specific code (and some of its variants) simply don't run by me. The first problem I get is `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'` (but fixing this gives me other errors).

Answer (score 3):

```
def dyna_join(df, positions):
    return pd.concat([df, df.iloc[:, positions].apply(','.join, 1).rename('new_col')], axis=1)


dyna_join(df, [0, -2])
```

[image]

Comment: and maybe add `astype(str)` if `int` or `float` column.