# Better to apply concat to pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a more efficient way of applying the below code. It is functional but when I start doing it to very large dataframes it becomes quite slow. Is there a more efficient way I can do functionally the same thing? The out put is just creating a unique column from a list of columns like col1_col2_col3.

```
df['unique_thread'] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: '_'.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
```

Comment: It seems there is a similar question, and various answers to that question. You could give try with those answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467327/add-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
df['unique_thread'] = df[cols].astype(str).agg('_'.join,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you try out BENY's answer, I would suggest you to have a look at these timing results:

```
In [15]: %timeit a[0] + '_' + a[1]                                                                                                               
250 µs ± 5.96 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [16]: %timeit a.agg('_'.join,1)                                                                                                               
675 µs ± 12.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Since you already know that you have to operate on 3 columns, you should do something like this:

```
df['unique_thread'] = df[col[0]] + '_' + df[col[1]] + '_' + df[col[2]]
```